# Should I be applying only to Junior positions if I only have QA experience?

Tags: job-search, united-states, job-change

My first "real job" is a QA position for a Government contract after attaining my associates. I fully understood with my degree, all I could reasonably expect at the start was simple test related jobs. I don't do much but QA software that comes in for verification. Reviewing code made in HTML,JS,CSS, as well as troubleshooting and debugging any coding mistakes that arise before returning it back for corrections.

I have experience in building automation software for use in-house built in pure python. I've been here for about three years or so and I'm not sure if I should keep trying to apply to software/dev jobs or try to find a Junior Position that has roughly the same pay as I do now (In the 50K's range).

Comment: How close do you come to meeting the stayed requirements for the job? You really don't have a lot of experience yet.

Comment: What is your education? What does your associates say you are? QA and development are two different jobs, and at least where I live, no amount of QA work would prepare you for a development job.

Comment: @keshlam what do you mean by stayed requirements?

Comment: @nvoigt Computer science, sorry, I thought that was a given so that is on me. I know QA and development are vastly different, so I was leaning on having to go in as a Jr. again but wanted to ask other people as well.

Comment: @Avila: Typo: stated requirements. I am coming to hate touch keyboards, and SE doesn't allow editing comments past five minutes.

Comment: @keshlam Ah I understand :) So/so is the answer. I can't stack up well when it comes to expert knowledge in python, or much in flask since I never used it. I understand the software dev process, and been trying to leverage my knowledge on communicating and working in teams with others, problem solving, version control, and other non-dev related skills. Though, your answer does help a ton and I understand better how to navigate this a little more, thank you so much

Comment: @Avila Don't talk about things you can't do. Focus on what you _can_ do. Debugging is an extremely valuable skill for a developer, and one that many developers lack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply for positions that you think you have the skills to do well in, based on what they say they're looking for. In your case that will probably be junior positions given your limited experience and the fact that you are shifting from process to coding, but it never hurts to apply.

Send an honest CV/resume with it. You might try pointing out in the cover letter (and in the interview, if you get one) that your experience in QC means you understand DevOps better than most beginners; you just want to spend more time in Dev and less in Ops than you have been doing. If it's a junior position, ask during the interview how much time you'll spend coding and how long it would take to get your first promotion.

After that it's just like any other application. Either they think you are a good fit for the position they are offering you or they don't. They're more likely to hire you as a junior, given what you've told us, but it's perfectly reasonable to try for some "stretch" applications as well. At worst, you and they waste a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

Apply for positions that you think you will have interest in, based on what they say your role will be. Know where your strengths and weaknesses are and try to take side projects that will help you build up the skills you're lacking while emphasizing on your résumé your aptitudes.

Based on your question, your work in QA has given you quite a bit of experience with operations. If you're open to DevOps positions, draw attention to your operations experience. You've also said that you were responsible for debugging and troubleshooting in your current role. Those are extremely valuable skills for a developer, and ones that many developers lack.

Don't worry about specific high-level imperative languages and technologies. Someone familiar with JavaScript can be writing Python or Java or C# in a week with help from the public documentation. Sure, you have to learn to `raise` instead of `throw` and that you make a function with `def` instead of `function`, but there will pretty much always be a one-to-one correspondence of concepts in one language with concepts in another. (Low-level languages like C++ and Rust or non-imperative languages like Haskell and Prolog have much steeper learning curves.)

Comment: This is amazing, thank you. This also helps a ton too. I'll keep my search while searching for small projects to do to help widen my skills. I also would've never thought debugging was a good skillset.  Thank you for your help